# Travis builds failing - Reason: The run destination iPad 2 is not valid for Testing the scheme 'UIKitPlus-Example'

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cocoapods, travis-ci

I'm having some trouble with my cocoapods running Travis CI. Everything seems to install correctly, but the xcodebuild script fails

```
$ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild test -workspace Example/UIKitPlus.xcworkspace -scheme UIKitPlus-Example -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO | xcpretty -c
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace UIKitPlus with scheme UIKitPlus-Example.
    Reason: The run destination iPad 2 is not valid for Testing the scheme 'UIKitPlus-Example'.
The command "set -o pipefail && xcodebuild test -workspace Example/UIKitPlus.xcworkspace -scheme UIKitPlus-Example -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO | xcpretty -c" exited with 70.
```

https://travis-ci.org/JamieREvans/UIKitPlus/builds/54649639

I'm not sure why this is failing, because I can run my tests on the iPad 2 simulator, using that scheme, without any issues.

Is this a Travis issue or is my Travis script wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to get it build by adding a destination to the xcodebuild command line, e.g. `-destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6"`

Comment: This works! However, I'm not sure why it's needed to specify a version. One of my projects, not only works on iPhones and iPads, but also all OS X devices, yet that's still failing. It shouldn't fail on iPad 2.